# How to check if some program is already installed and its version?

Tags: command-line

I'm exploring working with the ubuntu terminal. For particular reason I need to check if I have installed Python interpreter, like cPython. How to do it?
In general, how to check if some program is already installed and its version?

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get install <package>`?

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of all installed packages with

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

to get more info about a package try

```
dpkg -s <PACKAGENAME>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try these.

#### By which

```
which <packagename>
```

Example: which firefox

Correct Result: /usr/bin/firefox

#### By dpkg

```
dpkg -l | grep <packagename>
```

Example: `dpkg -l | grep firefox`

Correct Result: `ii  firefox 22.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.2  Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla`

#### Illustration

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To know the version of an installed package just use the `dpkg-query` command:

```
$ dpkg-query -W foo
dpkg-query: no packages found matching foo
$ dpkg-query -W unity
unity   7.2.0+14.04.20140423-0ubuntu1.2
```

Comment: @PeterMortensen Indeed, only the version string can tell if the package is installed or not, good point. Thanks